# lib files for standard library function calls missing on msvc

Tags: linker

I am trying to compile some c/c++ code using MSVC without the IDE. I get linker errors about some functions missing.

```
glfw3.lib(init.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_vsnprintf referenced in function _glfwInputError
msvcrt.lib(vsnprintf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_vsnprintf
glfw3.lib(context.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_sscanf referenced in function parseVersionString
msvcrt.lib(vsnprintf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__vsnprintf
```

But I don't know what turned the default libs off nor which I would have to link against.

Comment: Have you run `vcvarsall.bat` to set the required environment variables for the commandline tools? If not, read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Comment: I did. Without i would be able to run the compiler without specifying the whole path ;-) But thank you for your thought :-)

Comment: Best post the complete linker commandline from which the errors result.

Comment: I went back to cmake again. And I am afraid I don't have it anymore. But from what I remember: link.exe /libpath:"<path_to_glfw>" <some system libs like user32.lib> theglfw.lib main.obj /out:main.exe. And perhaps /Debug. Nothing more. Thats all and caused the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this post is quite old but the solution could be useful for other people as this problem remains with VS 2017.

I had the very same linking error and I found the solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5150eeec-4427-440f-ab19-aecb26113d31/updated-to-vs-2015-and-now-get-unresolved-external-errors?forum=vcgeneral) thanks to Andrew7Webb.

Apparently, the definitions of all of the printf and scanf functions have been moved inline.
Thus you have 2 options :

- Add `#include <stdio.h>` and the inline functions in your project ;
- Add an additional library to your linker input : `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` by editing the Linker Input in your Project Properties dialog box

I chose the second one and it worked perfectly.

See his post for a more precise explanation.